# what is the GROOVY connection string to an JDBC database with SSPI = True? I am running this from SoapUI Free version

Tags: jdbc, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to do this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance(
    url:'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\myDB',
    user:'server\user', //this I don't think I need because of SSPI
    password:'password',
    driver:'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',
    SSPI: 'true'
)
```

The problem I'm having is that this connection is just timing out. I can ping the machine. I can also connect to the database with Managment Studio logged into my SSPI user (or whatever you call it, I start the Management Studio with a different user)

So I've tried that with my SoapUI as well, started the program as a different user, but I still time out when I initiate the connection. So something is very wrong with my connection string and any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Yes, I don't know what's up with the \ backslashes after the URL to the server, I guess it indicates that it's at the root. If I don't use them I get a message that I'm on the incorrect version.

Answer (score 3):

And then we found the answer..... First of all I had the wrong JDBC driver installed. You need to head over to microsoft to get the real deal:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Then you need to unpack this one, place the 4 or 4.1 version in your bin directory of SoapUI. (You are apparently supposed to use Lib/Ext, but that doesn't work for me)

Then, since we are trying to use SSPI or Windows Authentication, to connect to the SQL server, you need to place the sqljdbc_auth.dll from the driver/enu/auth folder. This is used in one of your path's or in SoapUI Lib folder. *Remember to use the 32 bit dll for 32 bit SoapUI!!!* I did not since my system is 64.....

After this, I used this string, but now you have the setup correct, so it should work fine as long as you remember to start SoapUI up using the correct windows user. (Shif-right click - start as different user - use the same user you have started the SQL server with)

Again, I wasn't completely aware of this from the start (yes, total newbie here) and it failed.

Finally, when you have done all this, this is the string that works - and probably a lot of derivatives since the failing part here were the driver and dll.

```
def sql =Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;Database=myDB;integratedSecurity=true","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
```